# How to implement HUD

Tags: opengl, 2d, lwjgl, slick

I'm wondering how one could implement an HUD in LWJGL. I've seen tutorials on this, but they don't seem to work. I know the basic structure goes like this:

```
init3d();
// 3d code
init2d();
// HUD
```

To which, of course, init3d and init2d are the GL Initialization codes. And also, how would you draw the images for the HUD (or should I ask that in a separate question)?

If this is too vague, let me know and I'll update the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making a HUD/GUI with OpenGL (LWJGL)](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18468/making-a-hud-gui-with-opengl-lwjgl)

Comment: I know it is, but that one seemed to use a different engine. Sorry, I'm a newbie at OpenGL, so I don't know how to convert it

Comment: Is your game 3D or 2D? You have tags for 2D and Slick, but then you talk about `init3D()`. There's no engines involved and you asked about LWJGL, same as the other question. There's no converting to do.

Comment: It's 3D, but the question is about how to put a 2D image to 3D. And what about SDL_GL_SwapBuffers? How would I do that?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to handle this is to use a library that's specifically designed for GUIs. Check out [Nifty GUI](http://nifty-gui.lessvoid.com/). It works with OpenGL + LWJGL + Slick. Follow the [getting started](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/nifty-gui/index.php?title=Getting_Started) guide and read [the tutorials](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/nifty-gui/index.php?title=Tutorials). Finally, check out the source code for [the examples](http://nifty-gui.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=nifty-gui/nifty-examples-slick;a=tree). This will get you on your way the quickest, without needing to worry so much about the lower level graphics involved.

Comment: ok thanks! I knew there must have been a simpler way lol

Comment: Sure thing, if this answers your question you can accept the answer to show that.

Comment: once I figure out how to work it :D

Comment: That's fair enough.