# How to make a simple HUD with no library

Tags: c++, opengl, gui

I am writing a simple game in c++ using opengl in a windows system.

I have the scene and I need some informative text to appeared to the left top/bottom of the screen

I am printing these messages with a little plane and the text on it, but I want them to be aligned at the corners of the screen.

So I've read this question [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18468/making-a-hud-gui-with-opengl-lwjgl?rq=1) and I thought it seemed quite good and closer to my needs.

So, this is **some** of my code already used:

In init function of openGL:

```
glShadeModel (GL_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);  
glClearDepth(1);
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_FILL);
```

In the Resize function:

```
if (window_height == 0) window_height = 1;
glViewport(0, 0, window_width, window_height); 
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(60.0, (float)window_width/(float) window_height, 1.0, 550.0);
```

And finally in the render function:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(0, 0, -250); //is used for making the scene visible
RenderScene();
glutSwapBuffers();
```

I've tried using the ready3D() and then RenderScene() functions but the scene looked a lot different to what I was aiming.

How can I achieve this simple HUD (printing messages aligned to the window's corners)?

**Edit #1:**

This is what I see (terrain and message below):
[image]

I want the message to be aligned at the bottom left corner as well as other messages.

Comment: Please add some images of what you expect and what you get so we can see whats wrong.

Comment: @RoyT.: I've added the current state and a description of how I want it to look like.

Comment: Also note that you're using OpenGL in the old/deprecated way. A good read on the new way is this free book http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/index.html

Comment: @RoyT.: I have been told about it Roy, but this is what we were taught in class. I will surely check this for my next project.

Comment: Ah man I hate it when they teach terribly outdated stuff in class. Be sure to tell your teacher that his/her approach is frowned upon for over 5 years now (in a friendly way :P).

Comment: Indeed, it's frustrating that when I'll need to design something for example, in android, I would have to learn new stuff again :/ 
I will, in a friendly way :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the projection matrix properly first, from [OpenGL FAQ](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm) 9.030,

To set up a 2D projection, you need to change the Projection matrix. Normally, it's convenient to set up the projection so one world coordinate unit is equal to one screen pixel, as follows:

```
 glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
 glLoadIdentity ();
 gluOrtho2D (0, windowWidth, 0, windowHeight);
```

You can have more details from the [OpenGL FAQ](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm)

Comment: So I've managed to enable my 2D hud/gui, but I cannot manage to restore or even display only my scene (disabled the render2D) in 3D. Could you please tell me in which order should I write the calls in ready3D()?