# 2D graphic over 3D perspective projection

Tags: opengl, c++, android

To draw a 2D HUD (just a simple trianlge, for now) over 3D graphics in OpenGL I :

- draw all 3D objects, then
- call glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) before drawing 2D HUD
- draw 2D triangle
- call glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

however it seems I am missing something and the triangle is only rendered when I set Model-View-Projection matrix to Identity :

```
DrawFrame() {
.
.. // Draw 3D objects
.
/*
*  Coordinates of 2D triangle
vert[0] = 0.0f; vert[1] = 0.5f; vert[2] = 0.0f;   // TOP
vert[3] = -0.5f; vert[4] = -0.5f; vert[5] = 0.0f;  // LEFT
vert[6] = 0.5f; vert[7] = -0.5f; vert[8] = 0.0f;   // RIGHT
*/

glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

glm::mat4 guiMVP = glm::mat4(1.0f);
//glm::mat4 guiMVP = Ortho * View * glm::mat4(1.0f);   // This does not render triangle
//glm::mat4 guiMVP = Projection * View * glm::mat4(1.0f);   // This DOES render triangle at its place but in 3D world
glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &guiMVP[0][0]);
...
.. // render2D triangle
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}

OnSurfaceChanged(int width, int height) {

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    aspect = (float) width / height;

    // Projection Matrix
    Projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, aspect, 0.1f, 10000.0f);
    // Orthographic Matrix for 2D HUD
    Ortho = glm::ortho(0.0f, (float)width, (float)height, 0.0f);
}

setCamera(float cameraX, float cameraY, float cameraZ, float cameraLX, float cameraLY, float cameraLZ) {
    // Camera/View matrix
    View = glm::lookAt(
        glm::vec3(cameraX, cameraY, cameraZ),     // Camera position
        glm::vec3(cameraLX, cameraLY, cameraLZ),     // pointing at
        glm::vec3(0, 1, 0)      // Angle
     );
}
```

here's my **Vertex shader :**

```
attribute vec3 in_Position;

uniform mat4 MVP;


void main(void) {
    vec4 v = vec4(in_Position, 1.0);

    gl_Position = MVP * v;

}
```

This is screenshot of what I want :
[image: Desired Output]
I DO get this output by using an Identity MVP matrix for 2D graphics. I know this is an ugly hack that works for now.

**How to do this properly using Orthographic matrix ?**

Comment: When drawing 2D you don't need to apply view matrix. You only need the orthographic projection.

Comment: @concept3d thanks for guiding me, it works now. Would you add your comment as an answer, so I can accept it ?

Comment: similar for Java http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18468/making-a-hud-gui-with-opengl-lwjgl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When drawing 2D over 3D you don't need to apply view matrix. You only need to apply the [orthographic projection.](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html)

Applying the view matrix dones't work because it changes the position and rotation of the objects relative to the camera you don't want that.